# How to check for null int?

Tags: c#, null

Is this conditional check OK? It works fine but I'm wondering if there is a potential hidden issue. It sure is a lot simpler than having to check for null.

```
public int? myInt;

if (myInt > 0)
{
    Do something
}
```

Comment: If you want to check if it's `null`, check if it's `null`. `if (myInt == null)` or `if (!myInt.HasValue)`. If 0 is already an invalid value, why bother making it a nullable variable in the first place?

Comment: This check is correct if you really want to know if `myInt` is positive -- `null` is not considered positive (in fact, any comparison between a nullable type that's `null` and a non-`null` value is considered `false`; the language provides overloaded versions of the operators that apply to nullables "for free"). It is not correct if you want to test if there is any value at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will compile, but something like the following is probably safer:

```
public int? myInt;

if (myInt.HasValue && myInt > 0)
{
    Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.8) method of `Nullable<T>`, which returns the default value of the type if it's `null`, otherwise it returns the actual value (this works for you since you're comparing against `0`, which is `default(int)`):

```
if (myInt.GetValueOrDefault() > 0)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Note that it works for this particular case, but it is not a general transformation, because `default(int)` is `0`. If `myInt` is `null`, then `myInt == 0` is `false`, but `myInt.GetValueOrDefault() == 0` is `true`. If you really wanted this then arguably `(myInt ?? 0)` would be clearer still.

Comment: I think I said that already, but yes, if you want to know if the value is set to the default for the type, then `GetValueOrDefault` isn't useful.

Answer (score 1):

`int?` is a syntax sugar for `Nullable<int>` so you can call `myInt.HasValue` to check for null value.

[Nullable class reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.8)